# SQL Server Express delete SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-2016, sql-server-express

We have SQL Server Express v13.0 running.

I made a few export data Packages (SSIS) It was for a testing purpose, to see if my colleagues could run them too when I stored them in SQL Server.

Now I want to delete the packages I created before. I can't delete the packages by connecting to integration services with SMSS, since we have the Express edition.

Is there another way to delete (or edit) the packages that are saved?

Comment: Before asking your first question, it is recommended to read the [Tour Page](https://www.stackoverflow.com) to learn more about asking good questions, accepting answers and other website rules. Also to get your the *"informed"* badge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can access the SSISDB using express edition.

## Something to try

I am not sure if this will work in express edition but you should try to delete the packages using DTUTIL utility:

```
DTUTIL /SQL <PACKAGENAME> /DELETE /SourceS <ServerName>
```

**References**

- [dtutil Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/dtutil-utility)
- [DTUTIL Utility to Copy / Delete SSIS Deployed in MSDB to File System](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/63263/)

Comment: This doesn't work. Since we have an express edition.
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dtutil
Microsoft (R) SQL Server SSIS Package Utilities
Version 14.0.3006.16 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

This application requires Integration Services or Database Engine to be installed by SQL Server 2017 Standard, Enterprise, Developer, Business Intelligence, or Evaluation Edition. To install a component, run SQL Server Setup and select the component name.

Comment: @Gerband how did you stored them in SSISDB?

Comment: I stored them via the export data wizard in SSMS

Comment: @Gerband If there is another connected machine wher other vrrsion of sql is installed. Try running dtutil from it

Comment: @Gerband else i don't think you have access to SSISDB

Comment: @Gerband else i don't think you have access to SSISDB

Comment: ok, I will have to find another way to make clear which exports are the new ones. Thank you.